# Не работает роутинг yii2 в продакшене

Tags: php, yii2, маршрутизация

Не работает роутинг - могу попасть только на главную сайта

.htaccess в web есть:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: если правильно помню, то если делать через htaccess, то их должно быть несколько + прописывать в конфигах прилажения. Типа того - https://github.com/ilopX/yii2-basic-htaccess , но не знаю, рабочий ли это пример

Comment: Уточните, какой шаблон вы используете? basic или advanced?

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, включен ли в Apache этот модуль. У меня было такое - оказалось просто mod_rewrite был выключен.